# Let $\sigma\in S_n$ be an $n$-cycle, and let $\tau\in S_n$ be a $2$-cycle. Then, $\sigma$ and $\tau$ need not generate $S_n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles

> Let $\sigma\in S_n$ be an $n$-cycle, and let $\tau \in S_n$ be a $2$-cycle. Show by constructing a counterexample that $\sigma$ and $\tau$ need not generate $S_n$.

I know that $S_n$ is in fact generated by its cycles and its transpositions as I have proven this previously, so I feel like maybe I am just misunderstanding what is being asked. I initially approached this by trying to find an element of $S_n$ that cannot be written as a product of an $n$-cycle and a $2$-cycle, but this has not gotten me very far. If someone could nudge me in the right direction I would much appreciate it.

Comment: I believe the problem is meant to let you experiment with permutations. First consider the case $n = 3$ and see that here a $3$-cycle and a $2$-cycle do generate $S_{3}$. Then move on to $n = 4$, take WLOG $\sigma = (1 2 3 4)$ and start playing with the possible $\tau$. There is nothing like working out things yourself.

Comment: Also, note that if two elements $g, h$ generate a group, this does not imply that every element of the group is a product of a power of $g$ and a power of $h$. It could well be that you need consider elements like $g h g h g \dots$.

Answer (score 7):

Consider $\sigma=(1234)$ and $\tau=(13)$ in $S_4$. Viewed geometrically, we have four objects in a square where $\sigma$ rotates the square by $90^\circ$ and $\tau$ reflects the square on a fixed axis. But the symmetry group of the square $D_8=\langle\sigma,\tau\rangle$ is a proper subgroup of $S_4$, so permutations such as $(12)$ cannot be generated.

Comment: Anent the second paragraph, is it really necessary to give an argument to prove that the symmetry group of the square is a proper subgroup of $S_4$?

Comment: @bof "anent"? What is that?

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anent